# Confused with indices

Tags: differential-geometry

I have an equation that says $$\partial_{\mu}G^{\mu\nu}+\frac{1}{2}\epsilon^{\mu\nu\rho\sigma}\partial_{\mu}G_{\rho\sigma}=0$$
I am aiming now to move the $\epsilon$ from the second term to the first term. So,
if I want to multiply this equation (the two terms on the left-hand side) by $\epsilon$, I know I should not repeat indices.
So this will be 
$$\epsilon_{\lambda\gamma\eta\beta}\partial_{\mu}G^{\mu\nu}+\frac{1}{2}\epsilon_{\lambda\gamma\eta\beta}\epsilon^{\mu\nu\rho\sigma}\partial_{\mu}G_{\rho\sigma}=0$$
BUT I would have wanted that the first term simplify more into a dual of G, that is if the first term looked like $$\epsilon_{\lambda\gamma\mu\nu}\partial_{\mu}G^{\mu\nu}$$ this could have been written as $$2\partial_{\mu}\tilde{G}^{\mu\nu}$$. However I can not because I have to respect the rule that when I multiply by a term that has indices, I should use different ones than the ones that already are present.
My question is can I find a solution to this issue?

Comment: Are you saying you think this equation should reduce to $2 \partial_\mu \bar G^{\mu \nu} = 0$?  Because that's not going to happen.  The best you can get is $\partial_\mu (G^{\mu \nu} + \bar G^{\mu \nu}) = 0$.

Comment: @Muphrid What I meant, say, my equation was $C_1\partial_{\mu}G^{\mu\nu}+\frac{1}{2}C_2\epsilon^{\mu\nu\rho\sigma}\partial_{\mu}G_{\rho\sigma}$ where $C_1$ and $C_2$ are any constants. You said the only reduction I would get is $\partial_{\mu}(G^{\mu\nu}+\tilde{G}^{\mu\nu})=0$. What I am hoping I get is to move the epsilon to the first term (the one with the $C_1$) in order to make it a dual. VERY close to what you have written but for the sake of my calculations I don't want the second term to have the $\tilde{G}$ but I rather want the first term. (1)

Comment: My confusion is about the epsilon. I know that once I multiply the second term by another epsilon (with its four indices lowered) there is a rule that would let me get rid of it totally. But what indices should I use on this epsilon is where my confusion comes from. I hope I cleared my self out. Thank you. (2)

Answer (score 1):

The "rule" is that you should not use indices that have already been used *twice* - i.e. indices that have been contracted. It's totally fine to introduce a new $\nu$, since it appears only once in each term. You shouldn't have a $\mu$ on that $\epsilon$, though - since $\partial_\mu G^{\mu\nu}$ has one free index, its 4-dimensional dual should have three free indices - that is, the $\epsilon$ should have three new indices and $\nu$.

Comment: if you make check my comment above, because my intention is to get the dual to the first term. Thank you.